# Saving login credentials(username and password) through remember me checkbox

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I'm new to android and using Remember me checkbox for saving username name and password for the first time in my application. I have tried lots of code and did R & D for this function on Google but didn't succeed. In this app, the username(studentId) an password is fetched from server. I'll be thankful if some one help me in this. Thanks in

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginActivityB extends Activity {

String studentID, password;
TextView errorTV;

private CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox;
private Boolean saveLogin,saveAuth;
LoginDataBaseAdapter dbase;
private Handler handler;
EditText editTextUserName, editTextRe_enterPassword;
private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activity_b);
    ImageView btnSignIn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
    saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
    saveAuth = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveAuth", false);

   dbase = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(LoginActivityB.this);
    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editID);
    editTextRe_enterPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextRe_enterPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    TextView forgotPasswordTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTV);
    saveLoginCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rememberMeCB);
    errorTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorTV);

    if (saveLogin == true) {
        saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
    }

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            studentID = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String reEnterPassword = editTextRe_enterPassword.getText()
                    .toString();

            new AsyncCaller().execute();
            stopNewService();
            startNewService();
        }
    });

   public void startNewService() {
    startService(new Intent(this, com.education.service.MyService.class));
    }

public void stopNewService() {

    stopService(new Intent(this, com.education.service.MyService.class));
    }
public void connection() {
        final AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        myClient.setTimeout(60000);
        myClient.addHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myClient.addHeader("X_MOBICOACH_KEY", "MOBICOACH2013");
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("studentid", studentID);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("stream", "engg");

        myClient.post(Config.urlPath + "/SaveData", params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        if (response != null) {
                            if (response.contains("OK")) {
                                String userID = response.substring(3);
                                // String ID = removeLastChar(userID);

                                dbase.deleteAll();
                                dbase.insertEntry(studentID, password,
                                        userID);

                                if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                                loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", studentID);
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("value", "1");
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("userID", userID);
                                loginPrefsEditor.commit();

                                  } else { 
                                      loginPrefsEditor.clear();
                                      loginPrefsEditor.commit(); }


                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        DashboardActivity.class);
                                startActivity(dashboard);
                                finish();

                            }
                        }
  }
```

Comment: Where is your actual problem? Also: Don't store and transmit the password in plaintext!

Comment: where you facing issue?

Comment: everything is working fine but it does not save the studentid and password when login with remember me checkbox is clicked(true) in the edittext

Comment: Is this block of code `if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()` entered into? Try logging the if and else block.

Comment: @zohaib in your code on click of sign in button you are calling `AsyncCaller()` and in your posted code your doing all login and remember me task in `connection()` method. so which one you are actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to initialize `loginPrefsEditor`  just before you save the value to shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor= getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", studentID);
-----   
loginPrefsEditor.commit();
```

**EDIT:**
As requested in comments:

```
if (saveLogin == true) 
{
   // The below lines should be removed.
   // saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
   // Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashboardActivity.class);
   // startActivity(dashboard);
   // finish();

   // Instead, add the below lines:
   editTextUserName.setText (loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
   editTextRe_enterPassword.setText (loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));

}
```

This ensures that, if remember me checkbox was selected, the login screen would be pre-populated with username and password. User has to just click on the sign in button which will trigger the validation part and the button click listener logic would continue.

Comment: i did it the way you recommended but, now it is automatically login without asking for studentid and password

Comment: It means, the value is saved in sharedpreferences now :).. It is automatically loging in because of your code block ` if (saveLogin == true) `

Comment: then what should i do now ?

Comment: As per your code, if the saveLogin is true, then go directly to the next activity. That is what is happening. If you do not want to goto next activity, then build some checking logic in that block of code.

Comment: @zohaib: Since the sharedpreference saving problem is resolved, Please accept as answer by ticking the grey check box next to this answer.

Comment: @zohaib: Your problem was, sharedpreference value is not getting saved. It is now saving. So, this question is answered. Your other questions is you want to handle the saveLogin logic, for which also suggestion has been given. Please let me know what more you want!

Comment: where to apply save login logic ?, in the beginning where we initialize the loginPrefsEditor? Please help

Comment: @zohaib: save logic is correct. But, if '(saveLogin == true)', then you should only populate the edit text with username and password from shared preference. Only upon submit button click, you should move to the next activity. Hope this helps!

Comment: tried everything nothing happened, can you write the checking  login for code block ` if (saveLogin == true) `